# Symbolizing Raster using single Unique Value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, symbology

I'm dealing with a raster in GRID format. Currently it is symbolized in Unique Values and contains 5 classes. I'm trying to consolidate these to one class. Is there a way to do this and keep a single Unique Value?

Comment: Do you want to change the values in the raster, or just the way it is displayed (symbology)?

Comment: Hi Erica, I'm trying to adjust the symbology to only have one class. Is that possible without changing the values of the raster? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways I could think of to do it in the Symbology tab, which won't affect your original raster values:

1. Set each of the classes to the same color.
2. Select the five classes you want to consolidate. Right-click, and choose "Group Values." (This is described in "[Combining Categories](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000003m000000)" for grouping vector data, but it also works for raster classes.)

I'd personally choose the latter, just because it's more elegant.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that, and hopefully it works. I'm going to need to run a weighted overlay, and then reclassify. When I tried to change the symbology to Classified and 1 class the Weighted Overlay worked, but nothing showed up in the Reclassify tool.